# Storing Date objects in mongo and retrieving and comparing them

Tags: mongodb, date

my model looks something like:

```
var purchaseSchema = new Schema({
  forDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: moment().add(1, 'days')
  },
  name: Sting
}
```

Moment by default includes date and time.

```
"2014-12-19T01:23:56.000Z"
```

However later I wish to perform comparisons in my mongo queries such as,

forDate = (some specific date)

However these comparisons will not work, since in the database, we have both date and time.

How in this case must one store information in mongo and perform comparisons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you store it as an actual date, not as a string.

```
default: moment().add(1, 'days').toDate()
```

But as this is a default, you'll want to add this as a function:

```
var purchaseSchema = new Schema({
  forDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: function() { return moment().add(1, 'days').toDate(); }
  },
  name: Sting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your dates get stored as `ISODate` objects. Your driver will probably handle the conversion between the comparable objects in your programming language.

An ISODate will look like this when shown in the mongo shell:

```
> db.mycoll.findOne();
{
"date" : ISODate("2014-01-28T00:10:57.932Z"),
....
}
```